# Balance is not resetting outside the loop

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with nested while loops. When i run the below code i am getting the expected values for the first line of the outputted table but not for the second. I thought it was just a question of resetting the `balance`variable but i have doen that with no success.

```
while(rate_counter < 10)
{           
    rate_counter = rate_counter + 1;
    cout << rate;

    while(time_counter < 6)
    {
        time_counter = time_counter + 1;                    
        balance = investment * pow((1+ rate/100),time);                 
        cout << "\t\t" << setw(10) << balance;      
        time = time + time_increment;   
    }

    cout << endl;
    balance = 0;    

    time_counter = 0;

    rate = rate + rate_increment;
    time = time + time_increment; 

}           
cout << endl;               
return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
Rate             5 Years        10 Years        15 Years        20 Years        25 Years        30 Years
5.00           1276.28         1628.89         2078.93         2653.30         3386.35         4321.94
5.50           8513.31        11126.55        14541.96        19005.76        24839.77        32464.59
```

Problem is the second (and subsequent lines here) It should read.

```
5.50         1306.96   1708.14   2232.48   2917.76   3813.39   4983.95
```

Comment: You are only setting the value of `balance` inside the inner loop.  It appears to be declared outside both loops, so why would you expect it to be reset?

Comment: @ZacHowland it gets set (reset for subsequent iterations) inside the inner loop before it is used. Where else would it need to be reset?

Comment: @clcto If he is expecting it to have a different value between iterations, that is a question he has to figure out ... hence my question.

Comment: @ZacHowland look at his output: its a table of Rate and the `balance` after a certain amount of time.

Comment: @ZacHowland Sorry about that Zac, you are right. i posted a slightly outdated code sample. I have added the balance = 0; now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost correct. The issue is not that `balance` is not reset (it is set inside the inner loop before it is used) but that `time` is not being reset. Instead of

```
//...
rate = rate + rate_increment;
time = time + time_increment;
```

You want to reset the time to the initial value:

```
//...
rate = rate + rate_increment;
time = time_increment; 
// or maybe
// time = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find that it is easier to maintain these loops in the for-loop syntax:

```
unsigned int starting_rate = 500;
unsigned int ending_rate = 1050;
unsigned int rate_increment = 50;

unsigned int starting_time = 5;
unsigned int ending_time = 30;
unsigned int time_increment = 5;

for (unsigned int i = starting_rate; i <= ending_rate; i += rate_increment)
{
    double rate = i / 100.0;
    double balance = 0.0;
    std::cout << rate;
    for (unsigned int time = starting_time; time <= ending_time; time += time_increment)
    {
        balance = investment * std::pow((1 + rate / 100), time);
        std::cout << "\t\t" << std::setw(10) << balance;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 
}
```

Functionally, it is the same, but it puts all the loop maintenance together (separate from the logic you are doing in the loop).